# How to write function accepting nested Vect with specific element type?

Tags: idris

I want to write a function that accepts arbitrarily-nested `Vect`s whose final elements are of a limited set of types incl. `Double` and `Integer` (the "dtype"), and the function is aware of how many `Vect`s there were, and the size of each (i.e. the "shape").

For example, if my function's called `const`, I want `const 0.0` and `const [[0.0], [1.0]]` to compile, and the type-checker know that the first has no `Vect`s, and the second has two, with lengths 2 and 1. And I don't want `const [["foo"], ["bar"]]` to compile.

**What I've tried**

- defining a type alias for nested vects and using namespaces for overloads

```
Array : (shape : Vect rank Nat) -> Type -> Type
Array [] ty = ty
Array (d :: ds) ty = Vect d (Array ds ty)

namespace double
  const : Array shape Double -> Foo shape Double

namespace integer
  const : Array shape Integer -> Foo shape Integer
```

but because this is slightly backwards (the compiler has to infer the type from the return type not argument of `const`), this has trouble inferring the types (even for simple cases like `const 0.0`) in ambiguous contexts.

- defining an interface to keep track of the shape

```
interface Array ty where
  rank : Nat
  shape : Vect rank Nat
  dtype : Type

Array Double where  -- same for other types
  rank = 0
  shape = []
  dtype = Double

{len : Nat} -> Array ty => Array (Vect len ty) where
  rank = 1 + rank {ty}
  shape = len :: shape {ty}
  dtype = dtype {ty}

const : Array ty => ty -> Foo (shape {ty}) (dtype {ty})
```

but this doesn't work because Idris doesn't disambiguate between `Data.Vect.::` and `Prelude.::` in `const [0.0]`, even though I've only implemented `Array` for `Vect` not `List`.

Comment: Would something like `const (the (Vec 1 Double) [0.0])` work for your use case, or would it be too cumbersome in most cases?

Comment: @Cactus it would be too cumbersome

Comment: In Haskell I would solve this by making the `Array (Vect len ty)` instance more generic to `(f ~ Vect len) => Array (f ty)`. Not sure what the Idris syntax for this is.

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher can you maybe say what that means in words?

Comment: @joel In `const [0.0]` Idris doesn't know if you mean `Vect Double` or `List Double`, but it does know that it is `f Double` for some `f`. So an instance `Array (f ty)` would match. And then the constraint on that instance says that `f` should be `Vect`.